# In R, conditionally subset only those columns where the sum of specific rows is X

Tags: r, dplyr

**Background**

I've got a dataframe `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(task = c("a","b","c", "d","e"),
                 rater_1 = c(1,0,1,0,0),
                 rater_2 = c(1,0,1,1,1),
                 rater_3 = c(1,0,0,0,0),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

> df
  task rater_1 rater_2 rater_3
1    a       1       1       1
2    b       0       0       0
3    c       1       1       0
4    d       0       1       0
5    e       0       1       0
```

Raters are given rating tasks about the quality of a product -- if the thing they're rating is of good quality, it gets a `1`; if not, it gets a `0`.

**The problem**

I want to be able to subset only those rows whose column-sums for `rater_1`, `rater_2`, and `rater_3` equal a specific number. Put another way, I want to return only those rows where *n* raters (out of 3) marked "1" for their rating task.

A concrete example: if I were looking for any rows whose rater sums were **2**, I'd get a little subsetted dataframe like this:

```
  task rater_1 rater_2 rater_3
     c       1       1       0
```

**What I've tried**

I'm fiddling with `filter` in `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
  filter(sum(rater_1, rater_2, rater_3) == 2)

[1] task    rater_1 rater_2 rater_3
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

But it's not giving me what I want.

Comment: `df[rowSums(df[-1])==2,]`.

Comment: That seems to work. What's the `[-1]` doing there, though? (And feel free to write that up as an answer, I'll mark it correct!)

Comment: We want the sum of all columns except the first. Equivalent: `df[rowSums(df[,2:4])==2,]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rowSums` to get the sum of each row and then filter based on that. Since you want the sum of all the columns except the first, we apply it to the data frame accordingly:

```
df[rowSums(df[-1])==2,]
#  task rater_1 rater_2 rater_3
#3    c       1       1       0
```

Equivalent if, instead of `df[-1]`, we use `df[,2:4]`.